# Oracle non-CDB to CDB - Do I need to recreate dataguard?

Tags: oracle, dataguard

To convert from non-CDB to cdb it's necessary to install a new instance as CDB and so, to use `dbms_pdb.describe` in the non-CDB database to generate a xml of the non-CDB to add as a PDB in new CDB instance. The new CDB instance in dataguard side is installed with a normal `controlfile` (as primary database). This mean I always need to recreate dataguard? has someone made a conversion of non-CDB to CDB in a dataguard environment?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Doc 2273304.1. Essentially, you will need to set up a dataguard environment with your target CDBs and plug the non-CDB in to your new primary allowing the new secondary to redo the plugin.

There are special points at which you must pause redo apply on your old DG and make sure it is synced to appropriate positions so that it can be safely plugged in.

Make sure you test your process on non-prod at least a few times – [user217655](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/217655/andrew-sayer)